# Managing user login and registration for different websites that share same database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have multiple websites that share the same database but I am having a problem when creating the admin.

All these websites were sharing the same login and registration table. I could not make the emails column unique in the mysql db since same user can come across another website and sign up.

These became a problem since the users were creating multiple accounts on the same website. These made it hard to track customer orders. A user could create an order on website A, then create another account on the same website. So they could not access the order they created using account A.

I decided to create unique login table for each website. This solved the problem.

All these users from these websites channel order to one table and database.

The login tables have similar columns (user_id,first_name, last_name,email, password_hash, registration_date).

I am creating a single admin to manage these websites and users.

I would like you to help me find a way that I can have a view that will get users from all the login tables or you suggest alternative solution on how I can have a centralized table to access all the users registered from all websites.

I am unable to create a view since the login tables have similar user_id as the primary key.

Comment: You dont want a table per website, instead use one table and make the website a column in the user table! Also you may want to do the same with the ADMINS after all you may want to give admin rights to a single website and not all of them

Comment: I have site ids. However, I was unaable to stop users from creating multiple accounts for one website.

Comment: adjust the registration details and add a ` registration site` so that when the user tries to create a new account the script will check if the user has an account on the other site if yes - do what you want here. Use the same criteria for admin.

Comment: How about a single login page for all the websites? Once user login, they'll be shown a selection of which websites they have access to where they can select then get redirected from there.